# NetBeans PHP - Refactoring

Tags: php, netbeans

Are there any plugins for NetBeans IDE (PHP) that implements these refactoring?:

- Extract Method
- Generate Method

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/QafooLabs/php-refactoring-browser which lets you do extract method and some other things from the command line. It could probably used by a Netbeans  (and other IDE) plugin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I asked this question on NetBeans forum. You can vote for this functionality to be implemented here:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183807

Comment: After 4 years still no news about Refactoring (Extract Method, Generate Method , ...) for php in NetBeans ! :|

Comment: As of today (2014-04-28) still no Extract Method refactoring for Netbeans PHP IDE!

Comment: 6 years later and still no Extract Method feature for php :'(

Comment: Yearly check-in, still no support.

Comment: Still don't see it :\

PHPstorm does this great but it's $10 a month