# missing refactoring options in netbeans 7.4 for php

Tags: php, netbeans, refactoring

i recently started to study some of the refactoring options of netbeans. I am now using version 7.4 . In various tutorials such as [this one](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Refactoring) features such as "introduce method" and "encapsulate fields" are described. I cannot find them however in my php project. Am i correct in stating that these features are available exclusively for java and not for php projects?

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231921/netbeans-php-refactoring) old post and [this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183807) related bug it should be implemented by now also for php, perhaps i am missing something?

thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone has the answer to this?

Comment: These options are specific for Java projects, as you can see in linked bugtracker, this feature request is still open. As for class properties, there is getter/setter generator for protected/private members.